# MS Teams custom APP starts new bot session and display welcome message

Tags: microsoft-teams, chatbot

I've got a question regarding MS Teams Custom APP and chatbot:

Brief description: I have already installed a custom app in MS Teams for all my users. In this custom app a FAQ chatbot is configured. Currently, the bot only reacts when the user has made an entry. Then a main menu message appears.

Target solutions: For a better user experience, I want that the welcome message appears once the user clicks on the custom APP in MS Teams. Is something like this possible?

I look forward to your feedback and thank you in advance!

I searched for a solution in web, but nothing found. Here are some docs, but they don't cover my requirements:

- https://support.cognigy.com/hc/en-us/articles/4412112380690-Handling-a-welcome-message-with-Transformers-and-Endpoints#overview-0-0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-send-welcome-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Comment: Could you please confirm if you want to show welcome message each time user clicks on the application?

Comment: Can you please share the repro steps or some reference docs, so that we can investigate more on it?

Comment: @Nivedipa-MSFT - Yes thats correct.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft  I edited my question and now you see some links

Answer (score 0):

This scenario doesn't seem to be feasible

Using proactive messages we can send welcome message.

When the first time user interacted with the app that time we send the welcome messgae.

In onMembersAdded activity we write the code for sending welcome message.
This event get triggers only when new user is added.

Ref Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet